# Jath.js Xml parsing IE Error

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm using `jath.js` to parse XML with Xpath selectors.

But in **IE** Version 10/9, I am getting the below error:

> Object doesn't support property or method setProperty

Below is the jath source code which I'm using. I also tried the current version of the library and got the same error. My suspicion is that MS changed something in IEs XML Object. I hope you can help me.

```js
(function() {

Jath = {};
Jath.parse = parse;
Jath.resolver = null;
// values prefixed with literal charactar marker will not be
// treated as xpath expressions and will be output directly
Jath.literalChar = ":";

/**
 * Rudimentary check for IE
 * Also added support for WSH, uses the same API as IE
 */
var m_browser;
if (typeof WScript != "undefined") {
    m_browser = 'msie';
}
// TODO: is there a better way to detect node.js?
else if (typeof process != "undefined") {
    // running under node.js
    m_browser = 'node';
    var xmljs = require('libxmljs');
    exports.parse = parse;
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') > -1) {
    m_browser = 'msie';
}
else {
    m_browser = 'standards';
}

/**
 * parse:
 *    process xml doc according to the given json template
 *    @template - output spec as a json template
 *    @xmldoc - input xml document
 *    @node - the starting node to use in the document. xpath
 *        expressions will be evaluated relative to this node.
 *        If not given, root will be used.
 */
function parse(template, xmldoc, node) {
    if (node === undefined) {
        node = xmldoc;
    }
    if (typeOf(template) === 'array') {
        return parseArray(template, xmldoc, node);
    }
    else if (typeOf(template) === 'object') {
        return parseObject(template, xmldoc, node);
    }
    else {
        return parseItem(template, xmldoc, node);
    }
}

function parseArray(template, xmldoc, node) {
    var retVal = [];

    if (template[0] != null) {
        if (m_browser == 'msie') {
            xmldoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
            var nodeList = node.selectNodes(template[0]);
            var thisNode;
            while (thisNode = nodeList.nextNode()) {
                retVal.push(parse(template[1], xmldoc, thisNode));
            }
        }
        else if (m_browser == 'node') {
            var nodeList = node.find(template[0]);
            for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
                retVal.push(parse(template[1], xmldoc, nodeList[i]));
            }
        }
        else {
            var xpathResult = xmldoc.evaluate(template[0], node, Jath.resolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
            var thisNode;
            while (thisNode = xpathResult.iterateNext()) {
                retVal.push(parse(template[1], xmldoc, thisNode));
            }
        }
    }
    // we can have an array output without iterating over the source
    // data - in this case, current node is static
    else {
        for (var i = 1; i < template.length; i++) {
            retVal.push(parse(template[i], xmldoc, node));
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}

function parseObject(template, xmldoc, node) {
    var item;
    var newitem = {};
    for (item in template) {
        newitem[item] = parse(template[item], xmldoc, node);
    }
    return newitem;
}

function parseItem(template, xmldoc, node) {
    if (m_browser == 'msie') {
        xmldoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
        if (typeOf(template) == 'string' && template.substring(0, 1) != Jath.literalChar) {
            return node.selectSingleNode(template).text;
        }
        else {
            return template.substring(1);
        }
    }
    else if (m_browser == 'node') {
        require('util').puts(template);
        return node.get(template).text();
    }
    else {
        if (typeOf(template) == 'string' && template[0] != Jath.literalChar) {
            return xmldoc.evaluate(template, node, Jath.resolver, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;
        }
        else {
            return template.substring(1);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * typeOf function published by Douglas Crockford in ECMAScript recommendations
 * http://www.crockford.com/javascript/recommend.html
 */
function typeOf(value) {
    var s = typeof value;
    if (s === 'object') {
        if (value) {
            if (typeof value.length === 'number' &&
                !(value.propertyIsEnumerable('length')) &&
                typeof value.splice === 'function') {
                s = 'array';
            }
        } else {
            s = 'null';
        }
    }
    return s;
}
})();
```

Comment: You may want to try [jQuery XPath plugin with support for XPath 2.0](https://github.com/ilinsky/jquery-xpath) syntax that works cross-browser.